# While True and sleep in Uasyncio in micropython

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, esp32, micropython

I'm writing a surveillance camera app with *ESP32-cam* and MicroPython.

***tl;dr*** at the end

I'm using the Threaded code below:

```py
import camera
import machine
from config import app_config
from webserver import webcam
from _thread import start_new_thread
import time
import uos , os



start_time = time.time()


server = webcam()
server.run(app_config)

start_time = time.time()



def reb():
    print('reb')
    uos.umount('/sd')
    machine.reset()


sd = machine.SDCard(slot=3, width=1, 
                        sck=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['sck']),
                        mosi=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['mosi']),
                        miso=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['miso']),
                        cs=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['ss']))


time.sleep(5)

os.mount(sd, "/sd")

print(os.listdir('/sd')[:10])


def capture_image():
    while True:
        try:

            if time.time() - start_time > 3600:
                reb()
                break
            else:
                print(time.time() - start_time)




            buf = camera.capture()
            timestamp = time.time()
            time_str =  ''.join([str(i) for i in time.localtime()]) #str(timestamp) #'%4d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d' %(timestamp[0], timestamp[1], timestamp[2], timestamp[4], timestamp[5], timestamp[6])
            with open('sd/'+time_str+'.jpg', 'w') as f:
                f.write(buf)
                time.sleep(1)
                f.close()
            
            print('Captured image!')
            if len(uos.listdir('/sd')) > 5000:
                print('lottt')
                uos.remove('sd/'+sorted(uos.listdir('/sd'))[0])

            time.sleep(60)


        except Exception as e:
            print('we',e)
            pass
            time.sleep(5)

def reb():
    print('staeted sleep')
    time.sleep(3600)
    print('resetting ......')
    machine.reset()



utime.sleep(5)

start_new_thread(capture_image,())
time.sleep(2)
start_new_thread(reb,())

#from ftp import ftpserver
#u = ftpserver()
#u.start_thread()
utime.sleep(5)

do_connect()


camera.flip(app_config['vflip'])
camera.mirror(app_config['hflip'])
```

which works not bad , but its performance is not good , because of threading...

I tried using `asyncio` and changed the code to this, but it doesn't work healthy...
It just runs one time and one loop, then it stops...

```py
import camera
import machine
from config import app_config
from webserver import webcam
from _thread import start_new_thread
import time , utime
import uos , os
import uasyncio



start_time = time.time()


server = webcam()
#server.run(app_config)



start_time = time.time()


sd = machine.SDCard(slot=3, width=1, 
                        sck=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['sck']),
                        mosi=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['mosi']),
                        miso=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['miso']),
                        cs=machine.Pin(app_config['sd']['ss']))


time.sleep(5)

os.mount(sd, "/sd")

print(os.listdir('/sd')[:10])


async def capture_image():
    while True:
        try:

            if time.time() - start_time > 3600:
                reb()
                break
            else:
                print(time.time() - start_time)

            buf = camera.capture()
            timestamp = time.time()
            time_str =  ''.join([str(i) for i in time.localtime()]) #str(timestamp) #'%4d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d' %(timestamp[0], timestamp[1], timestamp[2], timestamp[4], timestamp[5], timestamp[6])
            with open('sd/'+time_str+'.jpg', 'w') as f:
                f.write(buf)
                await uasyncio.sleep(1)
                f.close()
            
            print('Captured image!')
            if len(uos.listdir('/sd')) > 5000:
                print('lottt')
                uos.remove('sd/'+sorted(uos.listdir('/sd'))[0])

            await uasyncio.sleep(60)


        except Exception as e:
            print('we',e)
            pass
            await uasyncio.sleep(60)


async def reb():
    print('staeted sleep')
    await uasyncio.sleep(3600)
    print('resetting ......')
    machine.reset()

async def main():
    uasyncio.create_task(capture_image())
    uasyncio.create_task(reb())
    #await uasyncio.sleep_ms(10_000)


#camera.flip(app_config['vflip'])
#camera.mirror(app_config['hflip'])

server.run(app_config)
uasyncio.run(main())
```

and if I use `run_until_complete` , I loose REPL input and output...

***tl;dr***
how to change this code to `uasyncio` compatible code?

```py
def capture_image():
    while True:
        try:

            if time.time() - start_time > 3600:
                reb()
                break
            else:
                print(time.time() - start_time)




            buf = camera.capture()
            timestamp = time.time()
            time_str =  ''.join([str(i) for i in time.localtime()]) #str(timestamp) #'%4d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d' %(timestamp[0], timestamp[1], timestamp[2], timestamp[4], timestamp[5], timestamp[6])
            with open('sd/'+time_str+'.jpg', 'w') as f:
                f.write(buf)
                time.sleep(1)
                f.close()
            
            print('Captured image!')
            if len(uos.listdir('/sd')) > 5000:
                print('lottt')
                uos.remove('sd/'+sorted(uos.listdir('/sd'))[0])

            time.sleep(60)


        except Exception as e:
            print('we',e)
            pass
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Have you tried working through [Peter Hinch's uasyncio tutorial](https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython-async/blob/master/v3/docs/TUTORIAL.md)?